# Updating records using radgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

here is my code

aspx

```
 <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn HeaderStyle-Width="25px" EditImageUrl="../images/Edit.gif"
                    ButtonType="ImageButton" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Comments" HeaderStyle-Width="400px" DataField="Comments"
                    HeaderStyle-CssClass="tblHeaderNoBorder">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblComments" Text='<%# Eval("Comments") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server" Height="40px" Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine"
                            Enabled="true" Text='<%# Eval("Comments") %>' BackColor="LightPink">
                        </telerik:RadTextBox></EditItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void RadGrid1_UpdateCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
     if ((e.Item is GridEditableItem) && (e.Item.IsInEditMode))
            {
                GridEditableItem item = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
                RadTextBox txtComments = (RadTextBox)item.FindControl("txtComments");
                RadGrid1.DataBind();
            }
```

here's the scenario, when i click on the update this must update the record.
how can i update the record? please help me.

I also set AllowAutomaticUpdate = "true"

Comment: Check if you have put update command or not.
You must have to create update command of the datasource related to radgrid otherwise it can't update.

Comment: Right now I can't see any datasource e.g. SqlDataSource for your Grid. You can also update using ADO.Net sql through code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have put update command or not.

You must have to create update command of the datasource related to radgrid otherwise it can't update.
otherwise you have to put update logic in

 `protected void RadGrid1_UpdateCommand`